# Integrate $\int\frac{x+y}{\sin(x)}\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to do the following integral
$$
\int\frac{x+y}{\sin(x)}\,dy
$$
but it's impossible with the things that I know, but maybe with MacLaurin?

Comment: x is a constant?

Comment: $\frac{xy}{\sin x}+\frac{y^2}{2\sin x}+C$?

Comment: The integral is with respect to $y$. Think about solving the following integral:
 $\int \frac{y+a}{b}~dy$ where $a$ and $b$ are constant.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following substitution to facilitate the calculation, $a=x$ and $b=\sin(x)$, then

$$\int\frac{x+y}{\sin(x)}\,dy=\int\frac{y+a}{b}\,dy=\int\frac{y}{b}+\frac{a}
{b}\,dy=\int\frac{y}{b}\,dy+\int\frac{a}{b}\,dy$$

Now you have two integrals that are easy to solve. Remember that $a$ and $b$ are constant, so the second integral is just the integral of a constant.

Can you finish the exercise? After integrating, do the replacement again to get the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\int \frac{x+y}{\sin x}dy=\int\frac{x}{\sin x} dy +\int\frac{y}{\sin x} dy=\frac{x}{\sin x}\int dy+\frac{1}{\sin x}\int y\ dy$$

Answer (score 0):

You're integrating with respect to $y$, so you can treat $x$ and $\sin (x)$ as if they were constants.